# Neo4J Windows Start-Service Error Failed to start service 'Neo4j Graph Database - neo4j (neo4j)'

Tags: powershell, neo4j

I am attempting to start the Neo4J service but I am receiving the following error. I have identified that the error is coming from the "Start-Neo4jServer.ps1" file. I am using the Neo4j version 3.3.3 on a Windows 2012 server. I am not sure how to debug the start-service or how to identify what is causing this error.

```
Get-Service neo4j

$result = Start-Service -Name neo4j -PassThru -ErrorAction Stop
$result


Status   Name               DisplayName                           
------   ----               -----------                           
Stopped  neo4j              Neo4j Graph Database - neo4j          
Start-Service : Failed to start service 'Neo4j Graph Database - neo4j (neo4j)'.
At line:4 char:11
+ $result = Start-Service -Name neo4j -PassThru -ErrorAction Stop
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

If i attempt to start neo4j through the console option then i have no issue:

```
cd /d D:/neo4j
bin\neo4j console
```

Answer (score 0):

When I have issues with Neo4j, the first thing I do to debug it is check Windows Event Viewer and the Neo4j logs folder.

I suspect that the Java environment path variable may have changed causing it to not find Java. Maybe you or Java itself automatically updated Java recently.

UPDATE: You said it started fine using console option so it can't be that.

Few things to try:

- Try with Administrator rights (you probably are)
- Reinstall the Neo4j service. "neo4j uninstall-service" and "neo4j install-service". You shouldn't lose any data.

You may have to add your neo4j.conf file.